# Can't move files to Xcode's simulator even using Apple's directions

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I would like to copy some file (PDF, XLS, etc) to my simulator for debugging with my app purposes.  I followed the directions from Apple "Sharing data with Simulator". They were quite straightforward, and are below.

When I tried this method nothing happened. No error msgs or anything.  The files simply weren't placed in the simulator when I looked within the Files app.

As well, I tried dragging the files from Finder to the open Simulator (both its desktop, as well as the Files app icon, and within the open Files app locations. All I would get is the error that those files could not be opened with the simulator.

I figure I need to find the simulator's path in the terminal window and then copy the files there, using terminal.  But when the closes I seem to get to is the path:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

And from there I get lost, and am unaware of where to look.  Many different directories and container names.

If someone could please tell me how (and where if in terminal) to copy data files to the iPhone simulator I would appreciate it.

Thank you

> **Add files to Simulator**
>
> To add files to Simulator, select one or more files in Finder on your
> Mac, then click the Share button. Select Simulator from the share
> destination list. Choose the simulated device from the drop-down list.
> Simulator opens the Files app, and lets you select where to save the
> files.

Comment: Finally found an answer that works, albeit a complicated one.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884248/how-can-i-add-files-to-the-ios-simulator

And the first answer posted by: bauerMusic